# How to check object is present in JSON or not Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecma

I have an array of the object `users`.

```
"users" : [
  {
     fname: "subrato",
     lname:"patnaik",
     password:"123"
  },
 {
     fname: "john",
     lname:"doe",
     password:"123"    
 }
]
```

I want to check whether the above JSON data contain the below object.

```
{fname:"subrato", password:"123"}
```

How could we do that in Javascript?

Comment: Expected Result : true if present and else false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're gonna need to loop through the array and do a check for it.

```
arr.forEach(obj => {
  if(obj.fname == 'name' && obj.password == 'password') {
    // Do stuff
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use JavaScript some function and it will return true if the object is found.

```js
let users = [
  {
    fname: "subrato",
    lname: "patnaik",
    password: "123",
  },
  {
    fname: "john",
    lname: "doe",
    password: "123",
  },
];
let check = users.some((x) => x.fname === "subrato" && x.password === "123");
console.log(check);
```

Answer (score 2):

Array.includes compares by object identity just like obj === obj2, so sadly this doesn't work unless the two items are references to the same object. You can often use Array.prototype.some() instead which takes a function:

```
    let users = [
  {
     fname: "subrato",
     lname:"patnaik",
     password:"123"
  },
 {
     fname: "john",
     lname:"doe",
     password:"123"    
 }
]
    console.log(users.some(item => item.fname === 'subrato' && item.password === "123"))
```